# Save time string with timezone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a database table with a column of type `time`. So far, I've been saving a "zoneless" time, e.g. `4:00pm`. I've been accepting this string "as is" and Rails has been happily saving this time string properly in the database.

I'm now having the need to save this value with a time zone. I'd like to somehow take a `4:00pm` time in EDT and save it in the database as UTC, `8:00pm`. (I realize that this 4:00pm was originally being saved as 4:00pm UTC.)

I don't particularly care how this `4:00pm` EDT time gets saved as UTC, although I'd prefer to take advantage of Rails' native behavior and not make my code more complicated than it needs to be.

It may be important to know that my Rails app is in the form of an API, so I won't be using any sort of form helpers or anything like that. I have to simply accept a string. I can, however, control the format in which that string is sent.

So, so summarize, **how can I save a string like `4:00pm EDT` as 8:00pm UTC in the database?**

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason why you are not saving as data type "Time with zone in database"?

Comment: Good question. I considered that, but I think the right way to store dates is to store everything as UTC.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of Ruby you are using? The `Time` class changed up quite a bit between versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that ruby's `Time` constructor interpreted the timezone correctly, you just need to call the `utc` method on the created object. Like so:

```
t = Time.parse("4:00pm EDT")
t.utc
```

If this date is set during a mass assignment, you may want to set a `before_save` handler on the model in order to set the time to UTC.

**Edit by OP**:

This is the exact form my solution ended up taking:

```
def earliest_arrival_time=(time)
  begin
    write_attribute(:earliest_arrival_time, Time.parse(time.to_s).utc)
  rescue
    write_attribute(:earliest_arrival_time, time)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this might be a good direction, although `Time.new('4:00pm EDT')` evaluates to `0004-01-01 00:00:00 -0500`. It parses `4` as the year as opposed to the hour. I'm looking into it, but mentioning this here in case you or someone else knows the answer off hand.

Comment: Okay, it needed to be `Time.parse` instead of `Time.new`.

Comment: If your `time` is a `Time` object, then `time.utc` should be enough, I was assuming that you had a string :) Still, my bad on suggesting `Time.new`, rather than `Time.parse`